# Configuring data access layer properties files in Spring Integeration testing environment

Tags: java, spring-mvc, testing, spring-test

I am setting up test environment for my Spring web application. I use `.properties` files and `Environment` to configure my persistence layer properties as shown below(I have skipped code for brevity):

PersistenceConfig.java

```
@PropertySources({
@PropertySource(value= "classpath:/com/hp/properties/persistence/mysqldb.properties"),
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/com/hp/properties/persistence/hibernate.properties")})
public class PersistenceConfig {

@Autowired
Environment env;

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.hp.model.entity"});

    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());

    return em;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties(){
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect.mysql"));
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.showsql"));
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.formatsql"));
    return properties;
}
}
```

I am creating my test classes using Spring's `WebApplicationContext` as shown below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={ApplicationConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@TestPropertySource(value = {"classpath:/com/hp/properties/persistence/mysqldb.properties", 
    "classpath:/com/hp/properties/persistence/hibernate.properties"})
public class PatientServiceTest {

MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
}

@Test
public void testForDependentBeans(){
    Assert.assertThat(webApplicationContext.containsBean("patientRepository"), Matchers.is(true));
}
```

}

But as I run the test I get an error about the intialization of `PersistnceConfig` as `hibernate.properties` is not found. I have also tried copying these files from `src/main/java` to `src/test/java` and add `@TestPropertySource` to explicitly provide the properties file. Yet I am getting the same error. Below is the stack trace if it helps.

Also, how can I load different properties file specific to test environment in Spring integeration testing than used by my production.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>       at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/hp/config/PersistenceConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:134)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
>       ... 25 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;